# Basic Authentication for All Except Listed User Agents in nginx

Tags: nginx

I've [written an analogous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45264481/basic-authentication-for-all-except-listed-user-agents-in-apache) about Apache configuration, but I'm also interested in nginx.

Is it possible to require Basic Authentication for all except specified User Agents in nginx configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several evenings of research and trial and error, I found that conditional authentication can be created combining `map` directive with custom variable for `auth_basic` directive:

```
map $http_user_agent $authentication {
    default "Access Restricted";
    "~^PayPal IPN" "off";
    # ...
}

server {
    # ...
    location / {
        auth_basic $authentication;
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
        # ...
    }
}
```